# New chapter on same page as old chapter ends

Tags: thesis

I am using documentclass thesis and would like to know how to make the new chapter start on the same page as the old chapter, without beginning it on a new page automatically?
Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also, thesis document class is not a standard one, so it would be best if you give us the source of that documentclass as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a onesided document then use `\let\clearpage\relax`

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}
bar
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\relax % no newpage
\chapter{baz}
foobar
\endgroup

\chapter{bazbar}
    foo
\end{document}
```